# Silent exceptions in Q:then callback?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have some issue with calling function of null variable in 'then' callback of Q.promise.

The first call (without Q using) will show an error, but while the second (wuth Q using) doesn't.

Small example:

```
var Q = require('q');
var nul = null;
var exp;

(function (exp) {
    var A = (function () {
        function A() {
        };
        A.prototype.foo = function () {
            var d = Q.defer();
            d.resolve('Hello, world');
            return d.promise;
        };
        A.prototype.bar = function (i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    /**
                     * That's all ok, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'qqq' of null"
                     */
                    console.log(nul);
                    nul.qqq();
                    console.log('ok');
                    break;
                case 1:
                    /**
                     * it's not ok, I see only result of "console.log(nul)", line 29
                     */
                    this.foo().then(function () {
                        console.log(nul);
                        nul.qqq();
                        console.log('ok');
                    });
                    break;
            };
        };
        return A;
    })();
    exp.A = A;
}) (exp || (exp = {}));

exp.a = new exp.A();
// You should run functions SEPARATELY!!!
exp.a.bar(0);   //  in that case: that's all ok, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'qqq' of null"
exp.a.bar(1);   //  int that case: it's not ok, I see only result of "console.log(nul)", line 29
```

I don't have any idea how to solve it

Comment: what is `nul`? what is logged by `console.log(nul);`

Comment: You're trying to call a function on `nul`, which is effectively null, that can't work. What did you want to do by calling `nul.qqq()`? You're not seeing the second error because execution stops at the first one. That's how JavaScript works.

Comment: @ArunPJohny `nul` is null variable (I need to thrown exception TypeError)

Comment: @Sosdoc You can run `bar(0)` and `bar(1)` separately and you will understand what I meaned

Comment: @indapublic ok, from what I understand your question isn't really about Q and silent errors, but a more generic one about error handling.

Comment: Client side or server side?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Whatever. I'm testing now in console by using `node`

Comment: @indapublic then `process.on("unhandledRejection"` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're not seeing the second error on the console is because Q catches all errors and lets you handle them separately.

You can handle an error in `then()` by chaining with a `catch()` function, in your example this can be done this way:

```
this.foo().then(function () {
    console.log(nul);
    nul.qqq();
    console.log('ok');
}).catch(function(error) {
    // do something with error
    console.log(error);
});
```

You can get this behavior also by using a try/catch block inside `then()` like this:

```
this.foo().then(function () {
    try {
        console.log(nul);
        nul.qqq();
        console.log('ok');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

## Old answer

Here are a few options for catching errors in JS/node.js:

#### Try/Catch blocks

These work like in their Java/C# equivalent, wrap each of the calls you make with a `try` block and catch an error, handling it in the `catch` block

```
try {
    exp.a.bar(0);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

You can also add finally blocks, check the type of an exception/error and so on, you can read more about it on the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

#### Node.js uncaughtException handler

In node, you can catch all uncaught errors, which will stop your program, by binding a callback to the `uncaughtException` event like this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (e) {
  console.log('Error: ' + e);
});
```

This isn't always the best thing to do in a program, but if you really don't want to stop the execution, this is an option.

Finally, I recommend giving a look to this [official article](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors) for best practices about handling errors in node.js

Comment: Please, run ONLY `exp.a.bar(0);` and then ONLY `exp.a.bar(0);`. You should to see difference

Comment: Your answer is not about question I mean

Comment: @indapublic You're right, sorry about that, I see the problem you're having and I updated my answer, this should let you catch any error/exception in your `then()` callback

Comment: Oh! Q catches all errors, I don't think about it :( Thanks, I will check some later. Thanks again